# How to print a String from a json file in PHP

Tags: php, json, printing

I've a problem.
I want to print out a string the string is in this JSON file with a php scipt:
http://api.worldoftanks.eu/2.0/clan/info/?application_id=d0a293dc77667c9328783d489c8cef73&clan_id=500030916&mt_order_by=-role_hierarchy

it's: data / description

i hope you understand what i mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [jsondecode](https://www.php.net/json_decode) php function.

```
$url = 'http://api.worldoftanks.eu/2.0/clan/info/?application_id=d0a293dc77667c9328783d489c8cef73&clan_id=500030916&mt_order_by=-role_hierarchy';
$jsondata = file_get_contents($url); //json data from url
$data = json_decode($jsondata,1); // convert json data to array
echo $data['data']['description']; // access data using keys of array, mapped to properties in json
```

Answer (score 0):

using [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode)

```
$json_uri = 'http://api.worldoftanks.eu/2.0/clan/info/?application_id=d0a293dc77667c9328783d489c8cef73&clan_id=500030916&mt_order_by=-role_hierarchy';

    $json = file_get_contents($json_uri);
    $data = json_decode($json,1); // convert json data to array
    $count = 1;
    foreach ($data['data'] as $key => $info) {
        echo $count++.' - '.$info['description'].'<br>';
    }
```